# Jquery css compare background-colour value

Tags: jquery

I have an `img`. On click it checks the background color of its parent and toggles the background color to grey if it is white and to white if it is grey.   here k have value that is rgb(255,255,255) (white) but the if loop sud be excuted but else part executed... means if is not working...   here in my code what happens when i execute it .... it only exectes only if part sometimes and when i change something it only exectes else part .... even if condition do not satisfy... like it should make grey when white and white when it is grey... but it did not.... i want to ask the condition which i have used ... is it correct...

```
function havetotha(it) {
    var k = $(it).parent().css('background-color');
    $('#message').html(k);
    if (k == 'white') {
        $(it).parent().css('backgroundcolor','grey');
    }
    else {
        $(it).parent().css('backgroundcolor','white');
    }
}
```

i figured it out ...

in if in condition i was comparing ($(it).parent().css('background-color')=="rgb(255,255,255)").... where rgb(255,255,255) is string but $(it).parent().css('background-color') it is not string so.... i used a trick i made two divs one with grey backgroun and other with white.... and compared there background with the my elements .... it works just take very long time to get into my mind..

Comment: Please take care to format your code correctly. Also, there doesn't appear to be a question here, just a statement.

Comment: why did you spell 'backgroundcolor' without the hyphen inside the if clause?

Comment: Please do specify the question...

Comment: if (k == 'rgb(255,255,255)') {
        $(it).parent().css('backgroundcolor','grey');
    }
    else {
        $(it).parent().css('backgroundcolor','white');
    }

Comment: is not working.... everything is complete but it is not working

Comment: Just check in the console whether the script is working or not.

Comment: Hope there is an error with the second line "$('#message').html(k);".I think the code breaks there. Just assign some other color to the parent div and check whether the else part is getting executed?

Comment: here what happens on a page load when i click it .... sometimes only if part executed.... and on changing code .... only else part executed..... it sud not have to be done... if it satisfies the condition.... so i want to ask u that the condition i have used is it correct.. or is it an object i have to convert it to string...

Comment: in if in condition i was comparing  ($(it).parent().css('background-color')=="rgb(255,255,255)").... where  rgb(255,255,255) is string but $(it).parent().css('background-color') it is not string so.... i used a trick i made two divs one with grey backgroun and other with white.... and compared there background with the my elements .... it works just take very long time to get into my mind....

Answer (score 2):

Please do specify the question... Chage backgroundcolor to background-color..
You can optimize your code as follows:

```
function havetotha(it) {
   var k = $(it).parent()
   $('#message').html(k);
   if (k.css('background-colour') == "white") {
      k.css('background-color','grey');
   }
   else if (k.css('background-colour') == "grey")({
      k.css('background-color','white');
   }
}
```

What is the purpose of the line :

> $('#message').html(k);

Comment: it just checks the value of k everytime.... there is nothing use of it ... just to check value of k.... main thing is wih if ... it is not working the way it has to

Comment: I didnt get what checking the value of k everytime means?

Comment: Actually in the second line k is assigned the value of $(it).parent(). If you give it every where, then it check for the parent element of it every time. If we are assigning a repeating element to a variable and then using that variable for further reference then the code will be better optimized.

Comment: in if in condition i was comparing ($(it).parent().css('background-color')=="rgb(255,255,255)").... where rgb(255,255,255) is string but $(it).parent().css('background-color') it is not string so.... i used a trick i made two divs one with grey backgroun and other with white.... and compared there background with the my elements .... it works just take very long time to get into my mind..

Comment: in if in condition i was comparing ($(it).parent().css('background-color')=="rgb(255,255,255)").... where rgb(255,255,255) is string but $(it).parent().css('background-color') it is not string so.... i used a trick i made two divs one with grey backgroun and other with white.... and compared there background with the my elements .... it works just take very long time to get into my mind..

Answer (score 0):

k should be declared before the function to be return or return result to a global var like this :

```
function havetotha(it) { return $(it).parent().css('background-color');}
k = havetotha(it);
//rest of the code
```